# Convert MBR to GPT hardisk

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

So i migrate from old laptop(MBR) to new laptop(GPT) by moving my SSD to new laptop, but new laptop cant detect my SSD since i installed it using MBR on old laptop.

I already convert my SSD using [this way](https://superuser.com/questions/1250895/converting-between-gpt-and-mbr-hard-drive-without-losing-data), it is succesths and my SSD marked as GPT when i ran `gdisk /dev/sdx`, but why my new laptop still cant 
detect my SSD like it is detect my GPT live usb?

By the way, my GRUB is installed on legacy mode.

Is there any next step i need to do?

Comment: Many SSD need firmware update. And UEFI/BIOS must be in AHCI mode for drives. If gpt and in BIOS boot mode, you will need a tiny 1 or 2MB unformatted partition with the bios_grub flag for grub to install correctly to gpt partitioned drive.If new laptop it probably is UEFI and also gpt. Does UEFI/BIOS see drive correctly (not as bootable device) as a hard drive in list of drives? Post these: `sudo parted -l` and `lsblk -f`

Comment: no, all this newlaptop detect for bootable disk is only my live usb stick with fat32 format

Comment: But is it recognized in UEFI or not?

Comment: i'm sorry, after reading more article i have come to where i can create EFI partition, and my laptop recognize it, the problem now, the partition still empty, now i have to search on how to install grub to EFI partition i made